# Populating body with media using AJAX and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, html

I am facing trouble getting an output to populate a page using JSON and Ajax. I have a page which look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Some Title</title>
<body onload="loadData();">
<div id="body-wrapper">
  <div class="preview-common">
    <div class="view-pane-common">
      <p class="save-hover">SAVE</p>
      <img src="dummy-data/new-preview.png" alt="Some Image" class="view-image-common">
    </div>
    <div class="info-pane-common">
      <a><span> Some Title </span></a>
      <p><span> By Some user </span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The class and id is required as I have a seperate CSS file which uses these classnames and id to style the page.

I wrote a script which look like this:

```
function loadData() {

  var mainElement=document.getElementById('body-wrapper');

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
    if (request.readyState === 4) {
      if (request.status === 200) {

        var jsonOptions = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) ({

          var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
          mainDiv.className = "preview-common";

          mainDiv.forEach(function(item)({
            var firstDiv=document.createElement('div');
            firstDiv.className = "view-pane-common";

            var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
            secondDiv.className="info-pane-common";

            firstDiv.forEach(function(item) ({
              var saveHover = document.createElement('p');
              saveHover.className = "save-hover";
              saveHover.innerHTML = "SAVE";

              var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
              imgElement.className = "view-image-common";
              imgElement.alt = 'Some Image';
              imgElement.src = "dummy-data/" + item.filename;

              firstDiv.appendChild(saveHover);
              firstDiv.appendChild(imgElement);
            });

            secondDiv.forEach(function(item) ({
              var aElement = document.createElement('a');
              var firstSpan = document.createElement('span');
              var pElement = document.createElement('p');
              var secondSpan = document.createElement('span');

              firstSpan.innerHTML = item.title;
              secondSpan.innerHTML = item.owner;

              aElement.appendChild(firstSpan);
              pElement.appendChild(secondSpan);
              secondDiv.appendChild(aElement);
              secondDiv.appendChild(pElement);
            });

            mainDiv.appendChild(firstDiv);
            mainDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);
          });
          mainElement.appendChild(mainElement);
        });
      }
    }

    request.open('GET', 'json-data/site-data.json', true);
    request.send();
  }
}
```

And the JSON file refered here is at path 'json-data/site-data.json' and all the media is at path 'dummy-data/' relative to index.html

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
     {"filename":"preview_1.gif","owner":"Sam", "title": "First Drawing"},
       {"filename":"preview_2.gif","owner":"Alex", "title": "Second Drawing"},
       {"filename":"preview_3.gif","owner":"Han", "title": "Third Drawing"},
         {"filename":"preview_4.gif","owner":"Tyler", "title": "Another Drawing"},
         {"filename":"preview_5.gif","owner":"Jane", "title": "First Painting"},
         {"filename":"preview_6.gif","owner":"Jack", "title": "Canvas"},
         {"filename":"preview_7.gif","owner":"Tony", "title": "Drawing"},
         {"filename":"preview_8.gif","owner":"Peter", "title": "Yet Another Drawing"},
         {"filename":"preview_9.gif","owner":"Stan", "title": "Sketch"},
         {"filename":"preview_10.gif","owner":"Steve", "title": "Second Drawing"},
         {"filename":"preview_11.gif","owner":"Logan", "title": "Fancy Icon"},
         {"filename":"preview_12.gif","owner":"Charles", "title": "Fancy Photo"},
         {"filename":"preview.gif","owner":"Lucy", "title": "Some Sketch"},
         {"filename":"new_preview.png","owner":"Drake", "title": "Tenth Cavas"},
         {"filename":"preview.png","owner":"Terence", "title": "Last Photo"},
]
```

I am not getting any output and not able to sort out what is wrong. Can some one please help me with a working solution with explanation. Thanks.

Comment: If your file is called 'site-data.json', then why are you trying to GET 'html-elements.json'?

Comment: Hey, the path is json-data/site-data.json . But it is still not working.

Comment: @codeAndCoffee your example code calls `request.open('GET', 'html-elements.json', true);`. If you've changed it to the right URL and still have the problem, then edit the question so we understand what steps you've taken. Also if you use request.response instead of request.responseText, you shouldn't have to do a JSON.parse.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question. I believe there is something wrong with syntax or loop sequence. Please check out the updated question.

Comment: you have got syntax errors everywhere. Look at your browser console. And you can't do a forEach on a div - it's not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was full of syntax errors and logical problems, to the extent that it's actually quite hard to be sure what you're hoping to achieve.

But here's an error-free version that does at least produce some output, hopefully this resembles what you are looking for:

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {

      var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
      mainDiv.className = "preview-common";

        var firstDiv=document.createElement('div');
        firstDiv.className = "view-pane-common";

        var secondDiv = document.createElement('div');
        secondDiv.className="info-pane-common";

          var saveHover = document.createElement('p');
          saveHover.className = "save-hover";
          saveHover.innerHTML = "SAVE";

          var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
          imgElement.className = "view-image-common";
          imgElement.alt = 'Some Image';
          imgElement.src = "dummy-data/" + item.filename;

          firstDiv.appendChild(saveHover);
          firstDiv.appendChild(imgElement);

          var aElement = document.createElement('a');
          var firstSpan = document.createElement('span');
          var pElement = document.createElement('p');
          var secondSpan = document.createElement('span');

          firstSpan.innerHTML = item.title;
          secondSpan.innerHTML = item.owner;

          aElement.appendChild(firstSpan);
          pElement.appendChild(secondSpan);
          secondDiv.appendChild(aElement);
          secondDiv.appendChild(pElement);

        mainDiv.appendChild(firstDiv);
        mainDiv.appendChild(secondDiv);

        mainElement.appendChild(mainDiv);
});
```

The issues were:

Firstly, every forEach had an extra bracket in the opening statement, e.g.

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) ({
```

should be

```
jsonOptions.forEach(function(item) {
```

The last left bracket is removed.

Secondly, forEach is only a valid operation on arrays. Div elements are not arrays, so doing forEach on them makes no sense and causes a runtime error. It's hard to see what the purpose of these loops would be even if they were valid. Did you want to loop the child elements of these divs? That would have some logic, except these are all new elements and don't have any children at the point where you are creating the loop. So I removed all forEach's on divs. Here are the docs on forEach, for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Thirdly,

```
mainElement.appendChild(mainElement);
```

throws an error because you are trying to append an element to itself. I assume this is a typo and you meant:

```
mainElement.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

Comment: Apparently, my problem was with syntax errors. The code is working now. Thanks!